# deal with datetime

Tags: python

Im new using python. I have a dataframe with 3 columns (id, beg, end) what to search clients that was connected to our website on the 2021-09-09 like shown in the expected ouput below.
the only data that i have is clients disconnected from beg date to end date.

**My initial dataframe.**

```
id  beg                      end                    
x1  2021-09-08 10:00:00      2021-09-10 10:00:00                
x2  2021-09-09 22:00:00      2021-09-10 00:00:00    
x3  2021-09-08 10:00:00      2021-09-09 10:00:00    
x4  2021-09-09 10:00:00      2021-09-09 14:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use excellent library to deal with date formats: https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: i have edited my original post @gbajson please have a look ^^thank you